# Wrting to HBase (MapRDB) from dataframe in Spark 2

Tags: hbase, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to write a CSV file to an Hbase table in Spark 2.0 on a Mapr Platform (5.2.0).

My program is as follow:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HColumnDescriptor, HTableDescriptor, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, Put}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

/**
  * Created by Mehdi on 2/25/2017.
*/

object CSVLoader {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(hbaseConfig)
    val tableName = "/tmp/TableCount"


    val convertToPut= (row: org.apache.spark.sql.Row) => {
      // create a composite row key: sensorid_date time

      val rowkey = (row.getString(0)+row.getString(1)+row.getString(2)+row.getString(3)).hashCode()
      val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey))
      val cfName=Bytes.toBytes("Column_Familly_1")
      // add to column family data, column  data values to put object
      put.addColumn(cfName, Bytes.toBytes("servedIMSIng"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)))
      put.addColumn(cfName, Bytes.toBytes("ggsnIPAddress"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(1)))
      put.addColumn(cfName, Bytes.toBytes("chargingID"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(2)))
      put.addColumn(cfName, Bytes.toBytes("sgsnIPAddress"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(3)))
      (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey)), put)
    }

    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      //.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
      .getOrCreate()

    // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
    import spark.implicits._


    //val peopleRDD = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")

    // The schema is encoded in a string
    val schemaString = "servedIMSI,ggsnIPAddress,chargingID,sgsnIPAddress"

    // Generate the schema based on the string of schema
    val fields = schemaString.split(",")
      .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
    val schema = StructType(fields)

    val df = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv("files/Sample_CSV.csv")
     // .select("servedIMSI","ggsnIPAddress","chargingID","sgsnIPAddress")
    // .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")

    df.show()

    // set up Hadoop HBase configuration using TableOutputFormat

    hbaseConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
    val jobConfig = new JobConf(hbaseConfig, this.getClass)
    jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
    jobConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
    df.map(convertToPut).rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)

  }
}
```

The df.show works in  show my CSV file but it can not write to Hbase. I get following error:

```
not take effect.
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|servedIMSI|ggsnIPAddress|chargingID|sgsnIPAddress|
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|        sd|           as|        rt|           dd|
|     mahdi|          red|         d|           dd|
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+

Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving object InterfaceStability
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1502)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1500)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.lock(Symbols.scala:546)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1500)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$coreLookup$1(JavaMirrors.scala:992)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$lookupClass$1(JavaMirrors.scala:998)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$classToScala1(JavaMirrors.scala:1003)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:97)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:38)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.toScala(TwoWayCaches.scala:33)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.toScala(JavaMirrors.scala:95)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToScala(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy.<init>(JavaMirrors.scala:163)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy$.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:162)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy$.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$copyAnnotations(JavaMirrors.scala:683)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$FromJavaClassCompleter.load(JavaMirrors.scala:733)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$FromJavaClassCompleter.complete(JavaMirrors.scala:744)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$coreLookup$1(JavaMirrors.scala:992)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$lookupClass$1(JavaMirrors.scala:998)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$classToScala1(JavaMirrors.scala:1003)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:97)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:38)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.toScala(TwoWayCaches.scala:33)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.toScala(JavaMirrors.scala:95)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToScala(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy.<init>(JavaMirrors.scala:163)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy$.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:162)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy$.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$copyAnnotations(JavaMirrors.scala:683)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$FromJavaClassCompleter.load(JavaMirrors.scala:733)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$FromJavaClassCompleter.complete(JavaMirrors.scala:744)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$info$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:127)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$2.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:171)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$coreLookup$1(JavaMirrors.scala:992)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$lookupClass$1(JavaMirrors.scala:998)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$classToScala1(JavaMirrors.scala:1003)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:97)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toScala$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:38)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.toScala(TwoWayCaches.scala:33)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.toScala(JavaMirrors.scala:95)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToScala(JavaMirrors.scala:980)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy.<init>(JavaMirrors.scala:163)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy$.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:162)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaAnnotationProxy$.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$copyAnnotations(JavaMirrors.scala:683)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$FromJavaClassCompleter.load(JavaMirrors.scala:733)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$typeParams$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:142)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anonfun$typeParams$1.apply(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:133)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:123)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$8.gilSynchronizedIfNotThreadsafe(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:168)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$class.typeParams(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:132)
        at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$8.typeParams(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:168)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.typeParams(Types.scala:1926)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.isHigherKinded(Types.scala:1925)
        at scala.reflect.internal.transform.UnCurry$class.scala$reflect$internal$transform$UnCurry$$expandAlias(UnCurry.scala:22)
        at scala.reflect.internal.transform.UnCurry$$anon$2.apply(UnCurry.scala:26)
        at scala.reflect.internal.transform.UnCurry$$anon$2.apply(UnCurry.scala:24)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)
        at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:115)
        at scala.reflect.internal.transform.UnCurry$$anon$2.apply(UnCurry.scala:46)
        at scala.reflect.internal.transform.Transforms$class.transformedType(Transforms.scala:43)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.transformedType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeApiImpl.erasure(Types.scala:225)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeApiImpl.erasure(Types.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.getClassNameFromType(ScalaReflection.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.getClassNameFromType(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$dataTypeFor(ScalaReflection.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.dataTypeFor(ScalaReflection.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:47)
        at CSVLoader$.main(CSVLoader.scala:102)
        at CSVLoader.main(CSVLoader.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Are my codes are coorect when writitng to hbase. I am running my application using using submit and in local[2] mode.

My sbt file is as follow:

```
name := "Asef"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"


resolvers += "mapr" at "http://repository.mapr.com/maven/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.1.1-mapr-1602-m7-5.2.0",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.1.1-mapr-1602-m7-5.2.0",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.1.1-mapr-1602-m7-5.2.0" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

my mistake was in the program:

```
df.rdd.map(convertToPut).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This was driving me crazy and the error was pretty cryptic.